# Access Windows Server Files via Linux with LDAP/PHP

Tags: php, windows, linux, active-directory, ldap

We are running a Active Directory with Windows Server 2008.
We have also a Linux Ubuntu Server 12.04 with Apache2 and LDAP.

Is it possible to access the Windows Server file-system via PHP/Javascript with the permissions of the user who is currently logged in the website?

Background: We are running Joomla and Mediawiki on the Ubuntu Server. A users writes an article and want to add some links to files and folders (!) on the Windows Server. IMHO the best way besides of tipping the link is in selecting the file/folder with a PHP/Javascript directory listing. But the user should only see the directories he has access to.
As I need the full path to the file/folder, an HTML-"input" field is no option.

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can use PHP to authenticate to the Active Directory server (**which probably means having the user's password in plaintext**), you will need to use PHP to list the files.

PHP has a `scandir()` function. Since the PHP would need to be given full **read** access to the Active Directory server, if you use PHP to ascertain which files the user can see, then you can simply show the ones they need.

You can get the file structure with this function:

```
function listdir($folder) {
    if (!is_dir($folder)) {
        return array(); //empty if not a folder
    }
    $return = scandir($folder);
    $subfolders = array();
    array_shift($return); //first two values are always .. & .
    array_shift($return);
    foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
        if (is_dir($value)) {
            unset($return[$key]);
            $subfolders[$value] = listdir($value); //recursively analyse the subdirectory
        }
    }
    return array_merge(array_values($return), $subfolders);
}
```

Please note I haven't tested this, so please tell me if there are issues.

[scandir() function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)